# Python xml to dataframe tag in tags

Tags: python, pandas, xml, dataframe, lxml

I have the following xml file:

```
<pdv_liste>
<pdv id="10" latitude="46" longitude="52" cp="01000" pop="R">
  <city>LA</city>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-02T09:37:03" value="1258"/>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-03T09:54:58" value="1258"/>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-06T12:33:57" value="1258"/>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-09T08:59:53" value="1258"/>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-10T10:38:39" value="1258"/>
</pdv>
<pdv id="2" latitude="46" longitude="53" cp="01000" pop="R">
  <city>NY</city>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-03T09:38:59" value="1258"/>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-06T11:19:09" value="1258"/>
</pdv>
</pdv_liste>
```

I want to obtain the following dataframe:

```
id latitude longitude city name   maj                 value
10 46       52        LA   diesel 2017-01-02T09:37:03 1258
10 46       52        LA   diesel 2017-01-03T09:54:58 1258
10 46       52        LA   diesel 2017-01-06T12:33:57 1258
10 46       52        LA   diesel 2017-01-09T08:59:53 1258
10 46       52        LA   diesel 2017-01-10T10:38:39 1258
2  46       53        NY   diesel 2017-01-03T09:38:59 1258
2  46       53        NY   diesel 2017-01-06T11:19:09 1258
```

I tried the following code:

```
df = pd.read_xml("myfile.xml", xpath="//price")
```

But I obtain the following dataframe that I do not want:

```
name   id maj                 value
diesel 1  2017-01-02T09:37:03 1258
diesel 1  2017-01-03T09:54:58 1258
diesel 1  2017-01-06T12:33:57 1258
diesel 1  2017-01-09T08:59:53 1258
diesel 1  2017-01-10T10:38:39 1258
diesel 1  2017-01-03T09:38:59 1258
diesel 1  2017-01-06T11:19:09 1258
```

There are multiple pdv. How I should change my code?

Comment: what do you mean by `very large`? Are there multiple `pdv_liste`, or `pdv`, or `city`, or `prices`?

Comment: There are multiple pdv. And large in size.

Comment: Can you give a *meaninfgul/valid* example ? There is a missing `</pdv_liste>` in the given one.

Comment: Forgot to add that. ```/pdv_liste>``` is in the end of the whole xml file

Comment: You're saying *"There are multiple pdv"* but your example shows only a single one.

Comment: Added another pdv example.

Comment: Side note: try to open this XML in Excel. Sometimes Excel handles these files very good and can produce tables which can be further imported to `pandas`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but excel ends up just importing the name of the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option with [lxml](/questions/tagged/lxml) :

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("myfile.xml")

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {
            "id": pdv.attrib["id"],
            "latitude": pdv.attrib["latitude"],
            "longitude": pdv.attrib["longitude"],
            "city": pdv.findtext("city"),
            "name": price.attrib["name"],
            "maj": price.attrib["maj"],
            "value": price.attrib["value"]
        }
        for pdv in tree.getroot().findall(".//pdv")
        for price in pdv.findall("price")
    ]
)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   id latitude longitude city    name                  maj value
0  10       46        52   LA  diesel  2017-01-02T09:37:03  1258
1  10       46        52   LA  diesel  2017-01-03T09:54:58  1258
2  10       46        52   LA  diesel  2017-01-06T12:33:57  1258
3  10       46        52   LA  diesel  2017-01-09T08:59:53  1258
4  10       46        52   LA  diesel  2017-01-10T10:38:39  1258
5   2       46        53   NY  diesel  2017-01-03T09:38:59  1258
6   2       46        53   NY  diesel  2017-01-06T11:19:09  1258
```

If you are tempted to use [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) to parse/save a spreadsheet in order to use [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) :

Open a new workbook, choose `Open/Browse/myfile.xml`, then click `OK` :

[image]

After that, confirm with another `OK` so Excel tries to infer the schema :

[image]

And finally, a new spreadsheet/table will be created :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

pandas documentation:

> for more complex XML documents, stylesheet allows you to temporarily
> redesign original document with XSLT (a special purpose language) for
> a flatter version for migration to a DataFrame.

So one of solutions is to denormalize your xml, using xslt transformation stylesheet. Here the code how to use it with pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

x_s = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pdv_liste>
<pdv id="10" latitude="46" longitude="52" cp="01000" pop="R">
  <city>LA</city>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-02T09:37:03" value="1258"/>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-03T09:54:58" value="1258"/>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-06T12:33:57" value="1258"/>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-09T08:59:53" value="1258"/>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-10T10:38:39" value="1258"/>
</pdv>
<pdv id="2" latitude="46" longitude="53" cp="01000" pop="R">
  <city>NY</city>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-03T09:38:59" value="1258"/>
  <price name="diesel" id="1" maj="2017-01-06T11:19:09" value="1258"/>
</pdv>
</pdv_liste>'''

df_style = '''<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/pdv_liste">
        <xsl:variable name="var1_initial" select="."/>
        <result>
            <xsl:for-each select="pdv">
                <xsl:variable name="var2_level" select="."/>
                <xsl:for-each select="price">
                    <xsl:variable name="var3_level" select="."/>
                    <ROW>
                        <id>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$var2_level/@id"/>
                        </id>
                        <latitude>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$var2_level/@latitude"/>
                        </latitude>
                        <longitude>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$var2_level/@longitude"/>
                        </longitude>
                        <name>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$var3_level/@name"/>
                        </name>
                        <maj>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$var3_level/@maj"/>
                        </maj>
                        <value>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$var3_level/@value"/>
                        </value>
                        <city>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$var2_level"/>
                        </city>
                    </ROW>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>'''

df = pd.read_xml(x_s, stylesheet=df_style)
df
```

As result I got:

```
   id  latitude  longitude    name                  maj  value city
0  10        46         52  diesel  2017-01-02T09:37:03   1258   LA
1  10        46         52  diesel  2017-01-03T09:54:58   1258   LA
2  10        46         52  diesel  2017-01-06T12:33:57   1258   LA
3  10        46         52  diesel  2017-01-09T08:59:53   1258   LA
4  10        46         52  diesel  2017-01-10T10:38:39   1258   LA
5   2        46         53  diesel  2017-01-03T09:38:59   1258   NY
6   2        46         53  diesel  2017-01-06T11:19:09   1258   NY
```